# Select an element of a drop down -selenium -python

Tags: python, selenium

I try of select the sport 'Football' in a drop down of sport but impossible of click on it.

I tried with the Select() method:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    url = "https://www.flashscore.com/"
    driver.get(url)
                        
    Team = 'Paris SG'
    Type = 'Teams'
    sport = 'Football'
                
buttonSearch = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".header__button--search"))).click()
fill_search_bar = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".input___1NGxU3-")
fill_search_bar.clear()
fill_search_bar.send_keys(Team)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dropDown").click()
select_sport = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class, 'dropDown__list')]"))
select_sport.select_by_visible_text(sport)
```

This code return this error : `UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>`.

Here is my second version:

```
fill_search_bar = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".input___1NGxU3-")
fill_search_bar.clear()
fill_search_bar.send_keys(Team)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dropDown").click()
select_sport = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//[@class='dropDown__list']/[contains(text(),'"+ sport +"')]"))).click()
```

This code return this error : `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='dropDown__list']/div[contains(text(),'Football')]"}`.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to break down the `wait until` class into two lines for simplicity. Its totally optional and wouldn't make much of a difference.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 300)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".header__button--search")))
element_to_be_clicked=driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".header__button--search")
element_to_be_clicked.click()
```

For the second part try using the values of the options in drop down list:

```
fill_search_bar.clear()
fill_search_bar.send_keys(Team)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dropDown__selectedValue dropDownValueSelected___3msxRQS']").click()
select_sport=Select(driver.find_element_by_class("dropDown__list dropDownList___3V-ppVu"))
select_sport.select_by_value('1')  #football has value 1 in the list
```